# Generic List in XE4

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe4

I get a compiler error message

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(18): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TList<IInterface>'

in Delphi XE4 when I do this:

```
uses
  Classes;

TMyClass = class
  private
    fIList : TList<IInterface>;
end;
```

Should I enable generics by a compiler option? Because when I remove the generic definition, it compiles. Other case it underline TList and IInterface as well.

Comment: Please include error message with code. It is important part of the question.

Comment: I get a compiler error. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I modified my question and inserted the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `System.Generics.Collections` unit to your `uses` clause.

This is where the `TList<T>` class is implemented, and the compiler will not find it unless you tell it where to look.